# How do I compress my GIF image to improve my Website?

Tags: html, performance, gif

I'm working on optimizing my website speed so that it is a lot faster. I have already compressed my image files, but one GIF that I have on my site is slowing everything down. The file size of it is 4.73 MB

I believe that's way too big for my site and is causing it to take a while to load. Anyone know how I can make the GIF compressed without losing quality of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes over 4MB is to big for everyone and everything. On this website you can find an comparison table for "gif size reducer" tools.

https://gifcop.com/best-tools-compress-gif-images/

You should think about your gif-file. 
Is the gif-file really useful for your users?

Comment: Thanks! How big do you think the GIF ought to be?

Answer (score 0):

gifs has no jpeg compression. You can only work on the gif trying to use fewer colors. For example you can use a flat background instead of a gradient. Another thing you can do is load the gif in a lazy way. Try searching for lazy load gifs or have a look here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/